# What is “inetinfo.exe” and how can I disable it permanently?

Tags: windows-7, process, bandwidth

I am currently using Windows 7. A process named `inetinfo.exe` is slowing down my laptop. It is eating all my bandwidth and I can not use my bandwidth at other activities which are important to me, while browsing Facebook pages are not loading after a long time because of it. How can I stop this `inetinfo.exe` permanently.

Comment: Run a thorough scan with your Anti Virus app. Inetinfo is part of IIS but something may have planted a virus with the same name.

Comment: Nothing found, showing no malware found in avast. @John

Comment: Windows 7 is now long out of support. See if you can uninstall IIS and reinstall it. Restart in between. If you do not need it you can leave it uninstalled.

Comment: How can I uninstall IIS?

Answer (score 3):

Please see:   https://serverfault.com/questions/61195/how-do-i-remove-iis-7

> Open Add/remove programs option in control panel.
>
> Click on Add/Remove Windows Component then uncheck Internet
> Information system.
>
> Then delete inetpub folder.
>
> Restart your system.
>
> Now (optionally) reinstall your IIS.